# Count by Grouping based on user preference

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a requirement to get grouped data and the counts based on UserPrefrenceCategory.
This isn't the actual scenario, but it's a similar, simple case of what I need to do:

```
public class ProductSale{
 public long ID {get; set;}
 public long ProductID {get; set;}
 public DateTime SaleDate {get; set;}
 ...
}

public class Product{
  public long ID {get; set;}
  public string Description {get; set;}
  public long ProductCategoryID {get; set;}
...
}

public class ProductCategory{
 public long ID {get; set;}
public string Description {get; set;}
}

public class UserPrefrenceCategory{
  public long ID {get; set;}
  public string Description{get; set;}
}
public class UserPrefrenceCategoryProduct{
  public long UserPrefrenceCategoryID {get; set;}
  public long ProductID {get; set;}
}
```

As per above structure, we need to generate report of product sale count grouped by USer Preferred Category using LINQ.
keeping in mind there may be possibilty that one product may exist in more than one USer Prefrence Category.

i have achived  count bylooping UserPrefrenceCategory and  filtering  ProductSale by list of products for each USer Preferred Category and getting count of sale for UserPrefrenceCategory.
i want to remove looping as this is not giving fast results, i need to implement in better best way to get these result using Linq.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

UPDATED

Here is my code

```
public static IEnumerable<ProductUserPrefrenceSale> GetProductSale(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            var sales= db.ProductSale.Where(x =>  x.SaleDate  >= startDate && x.SaleDate  <= endDate).ToList();
    var productids=(from r in sales 
                             group r by r.ProductID
                             into g
                             select (g.Key));

    var productGroupList = db.UserPrefrenceCategoryProduct.Where(x => x.Product.Any(s => productids.Contains(s.ID))).ToList()
                .Select(x => new ProductUserPrefrenceSale{ ID = x.ID, UserCategory= x.Description, Count = GetUserPrefrenceCategoryWiseCount(sales, x.Product.Select(s => s.ID)) }).ToList();

            return productGroupList;

        }

    }

    public static long GetUserPrefrenceCategoryWiseCount(IEnumerable<ProductSale> sales, IEnumerable<long> productid)
    {
        var result= (from s in sales
                                where productid.Contains((int) s.ProductID)
                                select  s.Count() ).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: Hi Stanley Code is added